# dlib installation error, cl.exe cant compile a simple test program

Tags: visual-studio, face-recognition, dlib, pyproject.toml

I'm having trouble installing dlib on **my laptop**.
I need dlib for using the face_recognition python package.
im using visual studio 2022 community.

so I have installed dlib before and I know how to install it. I know u r suppose to download visual studio and install the c++ part of it as well and install cmake using pip. i have done this before on my laptop a year back on python 3.6 and python 3.9.

a few days back I wanted to install it on python 3.8 but I keep getting the error below. so i taught python version had something to do with it. i had access to my college computer. i was able to install dlib on python 3.10.somehting on my college computer and it worked fine so then i installed the same python version on my  laptop and it didnt work(same error).

so from this i came to a conclusion that its not the python version and the problem is with my laptop. the error says cl.exe isnt  able to run a sample program and so I thought there might be a problem with visual studio. I installed and uninstalled visual studio multiple times(3 to 4 times) and i kept getting the same error.

there was another observation that I made, when I uninstall and reinstall dlib on the 2 versions(3.9 and 3.6) of python that I had used a year back, its able to install it properly without an error.

I spent nearly 8 hours on this and it is getting super frustrating! i would be so very grateful if someone would give me suggestions on what i could do in my situation.

*if the problem description is too long let me know*

is it possible that some other application i have installed is causing this?

```
C:\Users\Kharghuvel>pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.24.2.tar.gz (11.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [132 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      <string>:125: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
      Building extension for Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]
      Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310 -A x64'
      -- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
      -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.22621.
      -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.36.32537.0
      -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.36.32537.0
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
      -- Check for working C compiler: E:/Visual Studio community 2022/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.36.32532/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
      -- Check for working C compiler: E:/Visual Studio community 2022/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.36.32532/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
      CMake Error at C:/Users/Kharghuvel/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-t79xzg2d/overlay/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
        The C compiler

          "E:/Visual Studio community 2022/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.36.32532/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

        is not able to compile a simple test program.

        It fails with the following output:

          Change Dir: C:/Users/Kharghuvel/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-u47nsqdb/dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-310/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-9mnlfb

          Run Build Command(s):E:/Visual Studio community 2022/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe cmTC_27432.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0 /v:n && MSBuild version 17.6.3+07e294721 for .NET Framework
          Build started 7/17/2023 9:21:57 PM.

          Project "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
          PrepareForBuild:
            Creating directory "cmTC_27432.dir\Debug\".
            Creating directory "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\Debug\".
            Creating directory "cmTC_27432.dir\Debug\cmTC_27432.tlog\".
          InitializeBuildStatus:
            Creating "cmTC_27432.dir\Debug\cmTC_27432.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
          ClCompile:
            E:\Visual Studio community 2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_27432.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_27432.dir\Debug\vc143.pdb" /external:W3 /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\testCCompiler.c"
            Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.36.32537 for x64
            testCCompiler.c
            Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
            cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_27432.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_27432.dir\Debug\vc143.pdb" /external:W3 /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\testCCompiler.c"
          Link:
            E:\Visual Studio community 2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\Debug\cmTC_27432.exe" /INCREMENTAL /ILK:"cmTC_27432.dir\Debug\cmTC_27432.ilk" /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"C:/Users/Kharghuvel/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-u47nsqdb/dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-310/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-9mnlfb/Debug/cmTC_27432.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:/Users/Kharghuvel/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-u47nsqdb/dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-310/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-9mnlfb/Debug/cmTC_27432.lib" /MACHINE:X64  /machine:x64 cmTC_27432.dir\Debug\testCCompiler.obj
          E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "link.exe" could not be run. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.dir\Debug\cmTC_27432.tlog'. [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]
          E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]
          E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit() [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]
          E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost) [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]
          E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern) [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]
          E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TrackedDependencies.ExpandWildcards(ITaskItem[] expand) [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]
          E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.CanonicalTrackedOutputFiles.InternalConstruct(ITask ownerTask, ITaskItem[] tlogFiles, Boolean constructOutputsFromTLogs) [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]
          E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.PostExecuteTool(Int32 exitCode) [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]
          E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands) [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]
          E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute() [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]
          Done Building Project "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

          Build FAILED.

          "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
          (Link target) ->
            E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "link.exe" could not be run. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.dir\Debug\cmTC_27432.tlog'. [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]
          E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]
          E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit() [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]
          E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost) [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]
          E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003:    at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern) [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]
          E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TrackedDependencies.ExpandWildcards(ITaskItem[] expand) [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]
          E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.CanonicalTrackedOutputFiles.InternalConstruct(ITask ownerTask, ITaskItem[] tlogFiles, Boolean constructOutputsFromTLogs) [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]
          E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.PostExecuteTool(Int32 exitCode) [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]
          E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands) [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]
          E:\Visual Studio community 2022\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1127,5): error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute() [C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u47nsqdb\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-9mnlfb\cmTC_27432.vcxproj]

              0 Warning(s)
              1 Error(s)

          Time Elapsed 00:00:00.89





        CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        CMakeLists.txt:14 (project)


      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t79xzg2d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 416, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t79xzg2d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 401, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t79xzg2d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 218, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t79xzg2d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t79xzg2d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t79xzg2d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t79xzg2d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t79xzg2d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t79xzg2d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t79xzg2d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 343, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t79xzg2d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t79xzg2d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t79xzg2d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t79xzg2d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t79xzg2d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t79xzg2d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-t79xzg2d\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "<string>", line 130, in run
        File "<string>", line 167, in build_extension
        File "C:\Users\Kharghuvel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Kharghuvel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u47nsqdb\\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Kharghuvel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u47nsqdb\\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\Kharghuvel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Kharghuvel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u47nsqdb\\dlib_54426e676ce04cd8be1cffdfb8367a63\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. After searching a bit it looked like it was caused by build paths being too long.

What worked for me was to set the environment variables TMP and TEMP to c:\tmp

This makes pip use c:\tmp as the root folder for temporary files. The default is C:/Users/<you>/AppData/Local/Temp/, which is already quite long and then even longer files and folders are created inside.